Excel VBA UDF using Ubound returns #VALUE
Here is the VBA function I wrote:
Function test(x)
    test = UBound(x)
End Function

In excel I pass it the range A1:A5 which is filled with some numbers, =test(A1:A5). It returns #VALUE
I've tested this in two different machines, running brand new excel instances.
It does work in a Sub instead of a Function though. After running the following and inspecting the variables, a is 5.
Sub test2()
    x = Range("A1:A5")
    a = UBound(x)
End Sub

Any ideas?

A range is not an array.  You can use Cells.Count  or change it to an array:
Function test(x As Range)
    test = x.Cells.Count
End Function

OR
Function test(x As Range)
    Dim arr as Variant
    arr = x
    test = ubound(arr,1)
End Function

One thing to remember is that the array created by arr = x is a two dimensional array even if you pass in a single column.

Exceptions confirm the rule "..that the array created by 'arr = x' is a two dimensional array": if the assigned range consists of a single cell Excel don't assume a 1-based two-dimensional datafield, but changes the var type to a Variant :-;

Reinventing the ROWS Function (UDF)

Ranges are not arrays.
In Excel, a single-element array or a single-row array is a 1D array, while a multi-row array is a 2D array. In each case, the array is one-based.


Function GetRowsCount(ByVal x As Variant) As Long
    Dim RowsCount As Long
    Select Case TypeName(x)
        Case "Range"
            RowsCount = x.Rows.Count
        Case "Variant()"
            Dim ColumnsCount As Long
            On Error Resume Next ' prevent error if no 'UBound(x, 2)'
                ColumnsCount = UBound(x, 2)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If ColumnsCount = 0 Then ' 1D i.e. has no 'UBound(x, 2)'
                RowsCount = 1
            Else ' 2D
                RowsCount = UBound(x, 1) ' or 'UBound(x)'
            End If
        Case Else
            RowsCount = 0
    End Select
    GetRowsCount = RowsCount
End Function

